# Opening a non-default browser in Java

Tags: java, browser, uri

So I understand that using the method:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI.create("http://www.stackoverflow.com/"));
```

I can open a webpage with my default browser, but is there a way I can specify a path to a non-default browser and open a url with that one? ie. my default is Chrome, but I want to open in Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Runtime.exec()`. Mkyong has a [good example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/open-browser-in-java-windows-or-linux/) for you.

Comment: Hmm yeah, I've read up a little on the documentation. I see you can specify the "entry point". Thanks for the quick answer!